# How to alter the POS order item table header and columns

Tags: 8, commerce

Using Drupal 8/Commerce 2 and the [Commerce Point of Sale (POS)](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pos) module, the autocomplete form to search and add a product to an order shows this table header.

> [image: screenshot]
>   As indicated by @JayPan below, here is the code that outputs the header and the order item https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_pos/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/PosOrderItemWidget.php#L285

My requirement is to remove the Return and Quantity columns and add custom ones based on custom fields set in the Default item type POS uses. Thank you.

Comment: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_pos/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/PosOrderItemWidget.php#L285

Comment: I would remove the part asking where the header is set, show the code the comment from @Jaypan is linking, and ask how to change that header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the code, the table is generated as part of the form element for a field widget in `Drupal\commerce_pos\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\PosOrderItemWidget`.

You will need to create a class that extends this class:

```
namespace Drupal\example\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\commerce_pos\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\PosOrderItemWidget;

class ExamplePosOrderItemWidget extends PosOrderItemWidget {
  // Class methods go here.
}
```

You will then need to override the `formElement()` method (https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_pos/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/PosOrderItemWidget.php#L223)

`formElement()` generates the header for the table. You can call the parent, then alter the form object

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $element = parent::formElement($items, $element, $form, $form_state);
  // $element['order_items'] contains the table.
  // Make your alterations to $element['order_items']['header']
  // and $element['order_items']['rows'].
}
```

Note that `$element['order_items']` will contain the fully generated table. You should can remove any header items and column items you want, and add any new ones. However, you may want to also consider overriding `orderItemForm()` (https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_pos/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/PosOrderItemWidget.php#L321). This method generates the form elements for each table row. You could rewrite the implementation to not generate the elements you don't want, and to generate the elements you do. Then in your `formElement()` override, you will only need to alter the header of the table, as the rows will already be built with the elements you need.

After you have overridden the class, you need to implement it. There are two ways to do this, depending on your requirements.

If you want this table change to be across all field widgets of this type anytime this widget is ever used, you can use hook_field_widget_info_alter():

```
hook_field_widget_info_alter(array &$definitions) {
  $definitions['pos_order_item_widget']['class'] = 'Drupal\example\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ExamplePosOrderItemWidget';
}
```

You will then clear the cache, and now anywhere that the widget is implemented in the system, now or in the future, your override will be used instead of the original class.

If you want to be able to apply this change to specific fields, and still have the original implementation available, you can use your override class to create a new widget type by adding the widget annotation as the comments for your class:

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'example_pos_order_item_widget' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "example_pos_order_item_widget",
 *   label = @Translation("Example Pos order item widget"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "entity_reference"
 *   },
 *   multiple_values = true
 * )
 */
class ExamplePosOrderItemWidget extends PosOrderItemWidget {
```

Now the system will have a new widget type available, `Example Pos order item widget`. You can go to the field implementation(s) you want to change, and select this widget.

Comment: Thank you. D8 is still very strange, where do I place all these, within a custom module or within the .theme file?

Comment: The class will be in its own module and file, according to PHP PS4 standards. Unfortunately, the explanation for this is about PHP OOP coding, which is outside the scope of this Q&A. The solution I've given assumes and requires an understanding of how PS4 autoloading and PHP OOP class overriding work, which is a prerequisite of Drupal 8 module development.

Comment: Right, it's very clear, guess it's time roll up the mod development I've been dodging. I'll revert with what I come up. Really appreciate the details

Comment: this suggestions took a while to get use to but it worked! Answer accepted.